# Fill in no data polygons using data from surrounding polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4 and I have an **advanced license**.

I have a polygon shapefile that has 100000 polygons. The attribute table has two columns `Id` and `soil type`.

In my data, there are **1000 polygons** with **NO attributes** regarding soil type.

How can I use the **common soil type** in the nearby polygons to fill in the the attributes in polygons with no soil type?

Comment: Do you have any python ability? You would need an advanced license to use a tool like Polygon to Line with neighbor option http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003t000000 then join the lines to polygons left and right excluding empty and then find the largest length for each 'empty' polygon and calculate. This is not really possible without arcpy and an advanced license. If your polygons are slivers have a read of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000012000000 **be sure to keep a backup** before attempting Integrate.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson
Thanks. I have an advanced license. But I don't know python.

Comment: You could probably fumble through without it using an Excel pivot table or the like but it would really be easier in python. Are the empty polygons slivers or just missed records? They could be lakes or urban areas (concrete and asphalt aren't usually soil types).

Comment: You could try adding and calcing a unique id field (not FID or OID) buffering the empty polygons by a small amount (a foot or 30 centimetres), intersecting the buffer with the populated records then using summary statistics get the intersect area for case fields soil type and unique id then trim the rows (in Excel if you don't know python) to the maximum area for each soil type and unique id then attribute join the maximum table to the empty polygons and calculate over the join.

Comment: Best tool for that in my opinion is polygon neighbors. Not sure how you'll proceed with multiple neighbors if they have value. Perhaps majority...

Comment: Since you have ArcGIS Advanced license, I think you can use Eliminate tool: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/eliminate.htm . Select the polygons that you want to eliminate, and merge the selected polygons with neighboring polygons if they have the largest shared border or the largest area.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson
Thanks. I usually code in R. If you please could give me the approach how you will solve the problem in python, I could easily do it in R.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson
As I have these polygons with no attributes for rocks, land use and other variables in database in R, I was thinking about using specific packages (e.g. missForest) to impute the missing values. Any feedback regarding this approach?

Comment: I can't comment on that package, usually if I can't do something with existing tools I write my own rather than seeking 3rd party software. The bit that needs to be done in python is finding the largest adjacent code from the intersected buffers and valid polygons, I'd use a search cursor and a dictionary... I can't be much more helpful today, I'm really under the pump. @FelixIP has a good suggestion with polygon neighbors, from there you just need to find the largest length then join the table.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson
Thanks for your time and help